# Using chrome.action.setIcon() (Manifest V3) leads to TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIcon')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on toggling the icon for a Google Chrome extension, using [chrome.action.setIcon()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setIcon).

With Manifest V3.

My `manifest.json` contains the extension "action" property which **sets the icons correctly**:

```js
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/ext/icon16.png",
      "32": "/images/ext/icon32.png",
      "48": "/images/ext/icon48.png",
      "128": "/images/ext/icon128.png"
    },
  }
```

When running the code to change the extension icon, in the service worker ("`background.js`"):

```js
FUNCTION-WITH-ICON-TOGGLING(){
 chrome.action.setIcon({
            path: {
              '16': '/images/on/icon16.png',
              '32': '/images/on/icon32.png',
              '48': '/images/on/icon48.png',
              '128': '/images/on/icon128.png'
            }
          });
}
```

In a function run when the extension is pressed:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: FUNCTION-WITH-ICON-TOGGLING }});
```

I am greeted with a fun error:

```js
 Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setIcon')
```

I have tried changing syntax to even the original working icons, and the single icon path,
With the same error.
eg.

```js
chrome.action.setIcon({
            path: "/images/on/icon16.png"
          });
```

I have searched extensively and not found this error reported. If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate the help!

The full work in progress implementation can be found here:
[background.js](https://github.com/AndrewKhassapov/div-highlighter/blob/main/chrome-plugin/background.js)

Testing in Chrome Version 108.0.5359.96 (latest to date).

Comment: You can't use most `chrome` API inside a content script, which is what the injected function is. There's no need for executeScript in your example. Just call setIcon inside onClicked directly.

Comment: You're using `FUNCTION-WITH-ICON-TOGGLING` instead of the real function name. That's confusing, because `FUNCTION-WITH-ICON-TOGGLING` is not a valid Javascript identifier.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm !

Calling `setIcon` inside `onClicked` works perfectly.